# what's the question mark on this file means "twitter4j"

Tags: eclipse, twitter, twitter4j

I have file "`sample.twitter4j.properties`" but there is a question mark on it why?

and what does it means?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a file that is not in source control (whereas the ">" next to Crawler.java indicates that the file has changed).

Comment: Thanks for replying and help. I'm new in java and twitter4j . what do you mean by source control ? and is it a warning mark or not ?

Comment: You checked out the code somewhere (git?). It just shows that you added this file and it is not in the repository. Just like it shows that you changed Crawler.java.